# Can someone explain me the difference between ID3 and CART algorithm?

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart, cart-analysis

I have to create decision trees with the R software and the rpart Package.
In my paper I should first define the ID3 algorithm and then implement various decision trees.

I found out that the rpart package does not work with the ID3 algorithm. It uses the CART algorithm. I would like to understand the difference and maybe explain the difference in my paper, but I did not found any literature who compares both sides.

Can you help me? Do you know a paper where both are compared or can you explain the difference to me?

Comment: They use different loss functions, see wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_and_regression_tree#Formulae

Comment: The only difference then is ID3 uses Information gain with Entropie and CART the Gini Impurity?

Answer (score 6):

I don't have access to the original texts <sup>1,2</sup> but using some secondary sources, key differences between these recursive ("greedy") partitioning ("tree") algorithms seem to be:

1. Type of learning:

   - [ID3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm), as an "Iterative Dichotomiser," is for **binary classification only**
   - CART, or "Classification **And** Regression Trees," is a family of algorithms (including, but not limited to, binary classification tree learning).  With `rpart()`, you can specify `method='class'` or `method='anova'`, but `rpart` can infer this from the type of dependent variable (i.e., factor or numeric).
2. Loss functions used for split selection.

   - ID3, as other comments have mentioned, selects its splits based on Information Gain, which is the reduction in [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) between the parent node and (weighted sum of) children nodes.
   - CART, when used for classification, selects its splits to achieve the subsets that minimize [Gini impurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_learning#Gini_impurity)

Anecdotally, as a practitioner, I hardly ever hear the term ID3 used, whereas CART is often used as a catch-all term for decision trees.  CART has a very popular implementation in R's `rpart` package.  `?rpart` notes that "In most details it follows Breiman et. al (1984) quite closely."

However, you can pass `rpart(..., parms=list(split='information'))` to override the default behavior and split on information gain instead.

<sup>1</sup> Quinlan, J. R. 1986. *Induction of Decision Trees*. Mach. Learn. 1, 1 (Mar. 1986), 81–106

<sup>2</sup> Breiman, Leo; Friedman, J. H.; Olshen, R. A.; Stone, C. J. (1984). *Classification and regression trees*. Monterey, CA: Wadsworth & Brooks/Cole Advanced Books & Software.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/10Algorithms-08.pdf

Read ***1 C4.5 and beyond*** of the paper It will clarify all your doubts, helped me with mine. 
Don't get discouraged by the title, its about differences in different tree algorithms.
Anyways a good paper to read through

Answer (score 0):

ID3 algorithm can be used for categorical feature and categorical label.
Whereas, CART is used for continuous features and continuous label.

Comment: CART can also be used for categorical features and labels.

Answer (score 0):

The CART algorithm produces only **binary** trees, meaning trees where split nodes always have exactly two children (i.e., questions only have yes/no answers). However, ID3 can produce decision trees with nodes that have **more** than two children, since each node has as many splits/branches as there are categories. (Source: https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/)
Moreover, CART uses Gini impurity and cross-entropy for split criterion in classification, while ID3 uses information gain. (Source: *Machine Learning university course*).